# Overriding a base page class event handler?

Tags: asp.net

Let's say I have a base page class with a Page_load() event handler and I also have a Page_load() event handler in the derived page class. I realised you don't have to wrote vitual or override keyword and compiler does not detect error. Why is this? And why is is base class version executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. There was indeed a warning about shadowing a parent class method, but it was just a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 2):

Those are just events.

To override, you need to use the `OnLoad` method available on `Control`.

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding the event firing method and call your own. I can't explain why it's not complaining about both but I know they are added to the event, and hence are both in the queue to be executed.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page_Load(this, e);
}
```

The method you are overriding here doesn't do anything fancy except execute all event handlers in the queue. See the snippet from Reflector below:

```
protected internal virtual void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.HasEvents())
    {
        EventHandler handler = this._occasionalFields.Events[EventLoad] as EventHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```